# SSL certificate installation on aws ec2

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssl, ssl-certificate

An SSL certificate is typically issued to a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) such as "https//www.domain.com".However,my organizations need an SSL certificate issued to a public IP **(AWS EC2 Elastic ip)** address.

My questions is

Is it possible install ssl on public ip or public dns (e.g.,"http//c2-54-245-220-55.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com" or 54.245.220.55)

If it is possible then how ? 
please help me

Comment: is your intention to use it for multiple domains hosted on the same IP? If so, will such a certificate be accepted by browsers? (You'd have domain name in the URL bar, but IP address in the certificate)

Comment: "An SSL certificate is typically issued to a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)..." - no, its typically issued to an entity like an organization or person.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Thilo not i only want secure public ip

Comment: @Thilo actually my application is mobile application so no need for domain.

Comment: okay, no need for a domain. But why not get one anyway, as this will make everything much easier and more flexible. FWIW, no proper registrar should give you a certificate for an IP address that is obviously being operated by Amazon, i.e. not by you.